# How do I load and edit items (and also change the size of columns in code) into a datagrid in WPF (from a file)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've been dealing with issues loading and editing items from a datagrid in WPF.

Recently (about a month or so) I've made a question on this forum regarding saving and adding items into a datagrid (or listview when I first answered the question, then moved to a datagrid which is basically the same I suppose? but there's grids and you can edit items directly, just like excel. I think those are the main differences but correct me if I'm wrong).

Anyway, this is the code I have (saving and adding items into the datagrid): https://pastebin.com/HdC9dsJg

Basically, what I have at the moment to open (which doesn't work) is this:

```
Private DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos As Integer
```

'DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos (int) is how many Alimentos there are in the file
'PATH_DATABASE includes the folder name and the file location

```
Private Sub DATABASE_Abrir()
    Try
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Dim path() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(PATH_DATABASE)
        Dim lines As String

        For Each line In lines
            Dim item As STRUCTURE_Alimento(lines)
            sb.AppendLine($"{item.Categoria}|{item.Alimento}|{item.Calorias}|{item.Proteinas}|{item.Hidratos}|{item.Lipidos}|{item.Gorduras}|{item.Quantidade}")
            DATABASE_Alimentos.Add(New STRUCTURE_Alimento)
            DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos += 1
            If DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos = 1 Then
                StatusBarAlimentos.Content = DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos & " Alimento"
            Else
                StatusBarAlimentos.Content = DATABASE_QuantidadeAlimentos & " Alimentos"
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro: " & ex.Message, vbCritical, "Erro")
        End
    End Try
End Sub
```

Basically, what I was trying to do is:
For each line found in the text file, add a line in the datagrid. Then, inside that line, load the column details accordingly.

Right now, this is what I need to do:

1. Load items from the (text) file we just created in code;
2. Edit selected item directly from the datagrid and, after the changes are made, bind it to the 'ObservableCollection' we have (I believe that's what I have to do anyway, but you get the point);
3. Resize columns in vb.net code.

Also, I don't really know what's the purpose of these lines of code:
        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

```
    Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub
```

I'm assuming it'll check if the properties changed and if yes, it'll raise an event but how do I actually implement it?

Thanks

Comment: First off, you should go and actually read a basic WPF how-to example guide.  Without understanding the basics of fields vs properties, and classes vs structs, you are not going to gain anything from people spoon feeding you answers to basically code it for you. Is this your homework?

Comment: What's up, this isn't my homework, it's just a hobby of mine. By only reading code, you (or at least I) learn a lot from it but if you could point me to binding tutorials and whatnot I would appreciate that. I've never asked anyone to code it for me (it's not like every time I have a question I just post it in here), instead I provide what I tried (in this case is the raw code I posted here, not the link) and ask for help since I already searched for quite a long time (as I said in the beggining of this post, one month) and I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: You are off to a bad start here `Dim lines As String`       

       `For Each line In lines` Since lines is not any kind or of collection (actually it is `Nothing`) it cannot be iterated so your loop will never run.

Comment: For a tutorial on data binding in WPF try https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/

Comment: Thanks Mary (again), theoretically I was trying to do this: for each line found in the text file, add one row to the datagrid which with my updated code it works but I'm rather stuck at loading each item (between this symbol: | ) into the datagrid. Thanks so much for the tutorial, I will check that out!